# Dont understand how views work in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to understand ASP.NET MVC4.

Within HomeController I have code that seems to call a view ...

```
    public ViewResult RsvpForm()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And here is the view....

```
@model PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse

@{
    Layout = null;      
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>RsvpForm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
        @Html.ValidationSummary() 
        <p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) </p> 
        <p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</p> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" /> 
    }      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I dont understand is...

How come the view has access to data when I the call view with empty parameters?

And what this is for: `@model PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse`

What is going on with `x => x.Name`. I believe this is an anonymous function, but I dont understand the need for it. And I do not see where x comes from (it doesnt appear in the code above. Is it a global or something?).

To help with answers, I have done lots of PHP and web stuff and I have grasped most of C# and Razor, so I am assuming I am just being thick or this is something special for ASP

Thanks.

Comment: These are fairly fundamental concepts that you don't understand. I would recommend starting here: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: The view should not receive any data unless you explicitly pass the model to the view like so `return View(model);`

Comment: thanks @user1477388, so where does the x come from if it hasn't received any data? (the site does run without errors).

Comment: @Qerti Mporta. I have run thourgh a tutorial and done lots of reading up but I cont figure out these issues. I am hoping for some hints. Surely some one can give a few lines on where the 'x' comes from.

Comment: I see what you're asking.  Think of the x as a placeholder.  There doesn't have to be anything inside of it.  If you pass a model to the view; then x will have a value.

Comment: Thanks @user1477388, but I am not passing anything to the model as I have just `View()`

Comment: You don't have to pass anything.  Consider this code `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)`.  The `x => x.Name` part is a lambda expression.  The model gets passed to `TextBoxFor()`.  If there is data, it will fill the textbox; otherwise, it will be empty.  Look here for more info on lambda expressions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311046.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x => x.Name is an anonymous function - it's never executed.

In fact, the Html helper casts it as an `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>`.  This is similar to [anonymous functions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) or passing functions around in JavaScript (Well, Func is, Expression wraps that and allows access to the execution tree of the function - basically tons of metadata about the function itself).

Once in the html helper, `TextBoxFor`, there's a ton of extra processing and comparison of the expression tree against the model metadata.  Attributes get factored in and all that is used to build up the HTML (like [Required] or [Scaffold])

Your controller doesn't pass in data, but the view declares a strong model.

In the view, `@model PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse` does not mean any data is actually passed in. It merely declares the view as strongly typed and makes the model **metadata** available to Intellisense and the view compiler.  The Controller/View relationship is a whole lot more complicated than just a simple function call, unlike most PHP MVC frameworks (or basic PHP includes). The data the controller passes in gets wrapped up into the Page and ViewData with all the metadata and controller context and more.